# Did Joffrey believe that he is not the true-born son or heir, but a bastard?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Joffrey in *Game of Thrones* always seems to believe that it is king's right that he can do whatever pleases him.
He justified most of his actions by the same fact. However, he is always challenged for validity for his right on the Iron Throne. First, at the time of his coronation, Eddard tried to  reveal the truth to everyone. However, Joffrey got him punished as traitor. That time, Joffrey seems to believe that his father's friend was trying to seize the Throne from him.

After that Stannis declared the same thing and started war against him. He also got support from the Southern Lords for same reason.

So, does Joffrey start believing that he is a bastard at any point of time?

Comment: I have accepted the answer which satisfies me more. It does not mean that other answers are not relevant or incorrect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Tautologist's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39307/9718) gives evidence of possible moments of doubt - but there's also evidence he still believed Robert was his father until (at least almost) end.

This is from the scene where the small council hears of the red wedding in S03 E10 (the one which ends with Tywin sending the king to bed early):

> TYWIN: Any man who must say, "I am the king" is no true king. I'll make sure you understand that when I've won your war for you.
>
> JOFFREY (shouting): My father won the real war. He killed Prince Rhaegar. He took the crown while you hid under Casterly Rock!

From [transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=7882):

He's trying to one-up Tywin using the bravery and martial prowess of the man he believes to be his father - implying that it's the Baratheon not the Lannister side of his assumed ancestry that is the one to be proud of. A characteristically childish "My dad's better than you, coward!".

Something like this wouldn't leap to mind in a moment of passion or anger if he harboured serious doubts about it, and it wouldn't work as characteristically egotistical one-upmanship if Joffrey didn't believe he had both Baratheon and Lannister ancestry.

---

*Fun fact - substitute "Price Rhaegar" for "King Aerys" and the quote arguably becomes accurate. Technically Tywin wasn't hiding under Casterley Rock at that exact moment, but he had been.*

Comment: Actually I was thinking about including this in my answer, because my initial thoughts about this scene were identical. However after some thinking I came to conclusion that what he did wasn't really bragging about his father. What he wanted to achieve is to answer angrily to Tywin. In other words - he meant: "you were a coward during the war", not "my father was a great warrior during the war". Taking this into account this scene doesn't really prove that he didn't have **any** doubts about his father - he might have had them, but they were simply unimportant in this moment of anger.

Comment: "Boasting" was the wrong word, I've edited it - but the one-upmanship element (a characteristically childish "my dad's better than you!") only works if he does truly believe he's Robert's son

Comment: Well, yes, but in my opinion if you are angry you may easily forget about these small doubts that you are really trying to push to the very bottom of your psyche in the first place. I understand that you see it differently, I guess we simply won't agree on this part :-)

Comment: Yeah, personally I wouldn't ever bring up something that felt like a vulnerability or existential doubt in the heat of an intense argument. Then again, I'm not a sadistic child king born from incest, so I could be wrong :-)

Comment: This is a somewhat twisted train of thought, though.  Perhaps he *knew* at this point in time that he was not Baratheon's son, and was openly goading Tywin, who no doubt also knew. Tywin, however, would never publicly state this doubt - his family's power rested on this lie.  So this scene could actually be interpreted to show the opposite - Joffery knew he wasn't the heir, and was throwing this lie into Tywin's face to show who really held the reins and the power in their relationship. Tywin, of course, shuts him down without giving in, but this scene isn't definitive.

Comment: @AdamDavis from a sophisticated character, sure, that'd be a cunning way to twist the knife. But this is Joffrey. In fact, this is Joffrey mid-tantrum. He's never shown that level of sophistication, especially not during a tantrum. Also, when characters do use subtext like that, the actors and directors usually drop clues - a raised eyebrow, a pointed pause, emphasis... E.g. "My... *father* won the real war"

Comment: @user568458 Perhaps, but he's a teenager, and obviously pulling away from what his mother and others are telling him to do and defining his own path.  He's learning how to play the game, and it is still a reasonable possibility that he's a little smarter than he appears to be.

Answer (score 8):

He started having doubts, which he expressed in the [first episode of the second season](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_North_Remembers):

> Having heard rumors about his parentage, he confronts his mother. She
>   dismisses it as gossip spread by his enemies.

Whether he believed her or not we simply cannot tell. In the books he is not a POV character, so we don't know what his thoughts are.

However taking into account that Joffrey was (among other things) rather stupid I think it's highly probable that he really thought it's only gossiping and believed he was Robert's son until his very sad end.

Comment: You were *saddened* by the end of Joffrey? :P

Comment: You must admit that his end was sad, despite the fact that it made a lot people happy :-)